# Dialogflow POST: Method List Intents Code 400: Method: projects.agent.intents.list

Tags: python, google-api, dialogflow-es, nlp

In the API reference it is stated, that all parameters are optional, except for the project name.

But when I try this:

```
url = 'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/'+config["DFproject"]+'/agent/intents'
headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer "+access_token, 'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

I get:

```
{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': "Errors in '' intent: display_name is a required field.", 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}
```

I thought the display_name comes from the response.
So how am I supposed to set it?
This is the API: [Google API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22projects%2Fwebapplicationscorpus%2Fagent%22%7D)

Comment: I did a workaround. I cURL'ed with called os.popen() and converted the output into JSON. Not optimal but it works for now

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @AchielVolckaert Hey my CURL includes this, if it helps you a bit.  url = 'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/'+config["DFproject"]+'/agent:import'
 headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': "Bearer "+access_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}

Comment: @AchielVolckaert The solution i posted should help. Pls dont forget to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is you are using **POST** in your url. You should be using **GET** instead for retrievals.

If you want to play around with the API and cant seem to set up the authentication on Postman, feel free to use this : https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

and this for reference: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview